# computer 100% cpu and 90% memory

Tags: memory, cpu

My computer is slow to compile apps in android studio and run emulator.
I notice that it is using 100% cpu and 90% memory.

[image]

my question here is, if I update my memory to 8 gb will I have some gain? or because cpu is in 100% it will not affect the speed?

thanks.

Comment: You will likely to have very little or no gain - the reason 90% of memory is used is because the OS caches reads - as soon as the memory is required it can drop the cached reads and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your swap is used. In the memory section of the task manager. It can explain the use of the CPU. It wait for data from hard drive.

SWAP are use when your RAM is full to expand it on hard drive. But a HDD is very slow.

Comment: While this answer is well intentioned, the original question is really vague with no details and typhus question reads as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

It would help if you increased the amount of RAM that your computer has. However, I think that in your case, the main bottleneck is the CPU, and your chipset might not be capable of handling a lot of RAM, so you might want to consider getting a new computer.

Comment: While this answer is well intentioned, the original question is really vague with no details and typhus question reads as a comment.